# How to Optimize this for loop? There are any one lines?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this for loop inside another for loop.

```
for j in range(num_classes):
    dW[:, j] += (np.exp(feature_i[j])/sum_i) * X[i]
```

I was wondering if there is any way to optimize this code.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: In general for `numpy`, you can remove your looped index (in your case `j`) and it should work the same, so: `dW += (np.exp(feature_i)/sum_i) * X[i]`. But it can depend on the format of your arrays. Try what I mentioned, if it does not work, you need to show a short reproducible example.

Comment: Isn't this question more suited for codereview?

Comment: @Kraay89 this would be rejected on CR aa incomplete.

Comment: What have you tried?  `np.exp` works with an array, so `np.exp(feature_i)` should work.  Divide and multiply also.  But since you haven't told us anything about the arrays, we can't help in a more concrete way.

Comment: Shorter code is not necessarily faster code!